# JPG image colors change when opened on Illustrator/Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have logo which format is .jpg. That's the only logo file that my client has provided me. Now, when I open this file on Illustrator or Photoshop, it suddenly change its colors. Here's what I mean;

**This is how it looks when opened on Photoshop/Illustrator**
 [image]

**This one is how it should look, I had to take a screenshot because uploading the original file will result in the image above.**

[image]

**Does anyone knows what's hapening and how can I fix this?**

Answer (score 1):

My guess, and it is only a guess, is that your color and conversion settings may need reviewing.

1. Go to Edit/Color Settings. You will see the window shown below
2. Check your working space, normally you would like to work in a big color space like Prophoto
3. But more importantly, the color management policies should be reviewed and set to preserve whatever color space the document may have

I would be most curious if this may provide an answer.

[image]

Comment: Nope, this is not working. The problem is only happening with this certain file and I really don't know why.

Comment: @Josef, Can you post a small version of this file so we can experience it first hand?

Comment: I wish I could, but when I upload the file to imgur or somewhere else, it changes its original colors. I'm starting to thing the problem is on the file. Here's the upload I just did to Imgur http://imgur.com/zGos2RU

Comment: What format is this file in? What application created it? What are you using to view it "correctly"? If you can open it to get a good screen capture, can you now save it from the same application as a new file? I wonder if it has been saved in a particular color bit order in a special application? I do not know much about this subject but there are people to address it better.

Comment: The file is a JPG. I barely know anything about the previous designer and what was used to create the logo, I do know the file is pretty old. I guess I'll have to just vectorize the logo with the pen on Illustrator, that way I would be able to use it as a vector in the stationary that I'm creating. Anyways, thanks for the help @ACEkin!

Comment: @Josef, I am very curious, how did you get the "correct" screen capture?

Comment: on my desktop I opened the original file on Windows Photo Viewer and took the screenshot with [PrntSc](http://prnt.sc/)

Comment: Can you save that image as another format from the viewer?